# PHP Error A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php

PHP:

```
<p><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/calendar.png" alt=""><?php echo date('d m Y', str_replace('/', '-', $pet['pet_lost_date']))?> by <?php echo $pet['reg_first_name'].' '.substr($pet['reg_last_name'], 0, 1);?>.<b></b> </p>
```

Error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

It displaying Error. How can I resolve this Error please help me.

Comment: What exactly does `str_replace('/', '-', $pet['pet_lost_date'])` return?

Comment: My guess is the issue is `$pet['pet_lost_date']`

Comment: 13 /10/1996 replace with 13-10-1996

Answer (score 1):

`date()` takes an integer timestamp as the second argument, not a string.  Try `strtotime()`:

```
echo date('d m Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $pet['pet_lost_date'])));
```

But if your date string is in the proper format, don't replace:

```
echo date('d m Y', strtotime($pet['pet_lost_date']));
```

But be careful as `strtotime()` treats dates with a `/` as U.S. style dates `m/d/Y` and dates with `-` are treated as `d-m-Y`, or maybe that's what you are trying to correct?

Comment: Although correct, I believe this answer can be improved by suggesting to omit the use of str_replace as it is redundant because the 'strtotime()' function can handle a date delimited by `/`.

Comment: That is addressed as `strtotime` handles them differently, hence the _or maybe that's what you are trying to correct?_. But I clarified.